# How to add to tool-tip with some image or legends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a tool-tip which is working for text box, but the problem is that the user doesn't know that there is tool-tip for the text box. My question is what should I add to the text box that the user will know that there is tool-tip and not just when he hover it the tooltip will show.

```
<input class="path-width"  id="Url" name="Url" title=" services can be accessed. e." type="text">
```

Comment: for better usability you can put a small `?` icon before or after the input field.

Comment: Typically this is implemented differently, you have a link like so: `<a href='#' class='tooltip'>?<span>Your tooltip contents here</span></a>`, then you use CSS to make the span invisible: `a.tooltip span{display:none}` and then show it when the link is hovered over: `a.tooltip:hover{position:relative;display:block}` And tada, you have a tooltip that let's you put anything you like in it. Normally you always want to use some javascript to suppress the click event for the links. `l=document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip');for(i=l.length-1;i>0;++i){l[i].onclick='return false'}`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gixapopa/1/edit this is what i mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `title` attribute with `input` element you may use HTML5 `data` attributes. Here is the Tooltip made with `data` attribute and with pure css. In addition `input[type="text"]` elements doesn't support `:after` or `:before` pseudo element.

Lets Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gixapopa/1/edit)** First.

**HTML Code**

```
<p>
  <label for="id" datatip="Hi I am ToolTip">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" value="" />
</p>
```

**CSS Code**

```
p{position:relative; display:inline-block; width:50%;}
label:after
{
content: "?";
position:absolute;
right:-20px;
background:gold;
color:red;
width:18px;
height:18px;
font-size:.9em;
text-align:center;
border-radius:50%;
transition: all .3s;
border:1px solid red;
margin:0 0 0 10px;
}
label:hover:before
{
content:attr(datatip); 
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
right:-230px;
top:-100px;
top:0;
transition: all .3s;
width:200px;
border:1px solid red;
}

input{width:200px;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot voted up Kheema,currenlty you put this for all labels but I need it to specific one,how should I change it.

Comment: well you could use like  `label[for="one"]`; HTML will be:- `<label  for="one" datatip="Hi I am ToolTip">Name:</label>` check DEMO. http://jsbin.com/gixapopa/2

Comment: Can you please share the code for the second demo ?